# Drag and Drop API stops working with custom MIME type on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

**Question:** Are there known issues with Drag and Drop on Android Chrome or am I using the Drag and Drop API incorrectly? *(if neither, I'm going to assume it's a bug and submit a report to Chrome).*

**Issue:** I'm implementing a simple Drag and Drop interface that seems to be working fine, but is behaving strangely on 1 of 3 device/browser combinations that I'm testing.  I've determined that the problem is in the specification of a custom MIME type `'text/custom'` that I set on the `'dragstart'` event of the `draggable` element, but nothing I'm reading in the Living Standard or on MDN is leading me to believe that this should be a problem.

It works fine on Chrome on my desktop (`Windows 10, Chrome 97.0.4692.71`) and the iPhone 8 I'm testing (`iOS 15.0, Chrome 94.0.4606.76`), but fails on Chrome on my Galaxy S20 (`Android 11, Chrome 96.0.4664.104`).

As soon as I revert the MIME type in `draggable.setData(...)` from `'text/custom'` to `'text/plain'`, all interfaces work as expected, but I'd like to have a custom MIME type if possible, and I haven't found anything online that would lead me to believe that I can't do that.

**Why do I care?:**   I want an understanding of what's happening most of all, but the reason for trying to use a custom MIME type is to bail out of the various `'drag...'` handlers on `container` (with an `e.dataTransfer.types.includes('text/custom')` check) for any other `draggable` interactions that may incidentally cross paths with my interface (eg: dragging a file from the OS into the browser on my page or dragging a link/URL across `container`).

**Code (stripped as much as possible for minimal demonstration of issue):**

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <style>
    #container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 150px;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    #draggable-tester {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      height: 40px;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">Container</div>
  <div id="draggable-tester" draggable="true">Draggable</div>

  <script>
    const draggableMimeType = 'text/custom';

    // Initialize draggable element.
    const draggable = document.getElementById('draggable-tester');
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
      e.dataTransfer.setData(draggableMimeType, 'data payload');
      console.log('dragstart event fired on draggable');
    });
    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      console.log('dragend event fired on draggable');
    });

    // Initialize drag container and drop zone.
    const dragContainer = document.getElementById('container');
    dragContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('dragenter event fired on container');
    });
    dragContainer.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    dragContainer.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
      console.log(`drop w/ data: '${e.dataTransfer.getData(draggableMimeType)}'`);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**Results:** On desktop and iPhone, the above gives me the expected results as I execute the various drag actions on the drag container and drop the `draggable` element, but on Android it only logs the `'dragstart'` message (it doesn't even log the `'dragend'` registered on `draggable`).  As soon as I modify `draggableMimeType` to be `'text/plain'`, it works on all devices as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug.  I've submitted an issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1293803

I'm working around it in the meantime by sidestepping the Drag and Drop API's data provision mechanism altogether.  Apparently you have to call `setData()` in the `dragstart` handler in order for the `draggable` interaction to work at all, but I never utilize the other half of that interaction with `getData`.

Instead, I'm sharing a little bit of "global" state (it's only global across a few dozen lines inside of a module) across the various event handlers, with `dragstart` setting the global to house our element that is currently being dragged and all of the container `drag...` events looking at that global for indication as to whether the drag pertains to our custom `draggable` element or some other element from out in the wild (eg: files from other contexts/applications or links dragged through the interface (in which case it just bails out)). `dragend` is then responsible for setting the global to `undefined` so that we're appropriately maintaining our indication of whether a drag is supposed to be handled by our own logic.

A small snippet:

```
// Establish a global for tracking the in-house element currently being dragged.
let draggingElement = undefined;

// Initialize draggable element.
const draggable = document.getElementById('draggable-tester');
draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '');
  draggingElement = draggable;
  console.log('dragstart event fired on draggable');
});
draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
  draggingElement = undefined;
  console.log('dragend event fired on draggable');
});

// Initialize drag container and drop zone.
const dragContainer = document.getElementById('container');
dragContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
  if (!draggingElement) return;

  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('dragenter event fired on container');
});
dragContainer.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  if (!draggingElement) return;

  e.preventDefault();
});
dragContainer.addEventListener('drop', () => {
  if (!draggingElement) return;

  console.log(`dropping element w/ id: "${draggingElement.getAttribute('id')}"`);
});
```